# Generating Valid Keypairs on Hedera Blockchain

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

I've been trying to send funds to addresses i generated using the hedera-js-sdk, the transaction is sent successfully, but always fails with an `INSUFFICIENT ACCOUNT BALANCE` error in the explorer. 
Alternatively, when i copy a public key from `portal.hedera.com` and try sending HBARs to it, the transaction is processed successfully.
I cant seem to figure out what im doing wrong.
Can anyone offer any help pls? 
Thanks.
Below is the code and transaction hash:

```
const { PublicKey,  Hbar, TransferTransaction,  } = require("@hashgraph/sdk");

export const generateHederaAccountId = (publicKey: string) => {
    let _publicKey = new PublicKey(publicKey)
    return _publicKey.toAccountId(0, 0).toString();
}


export const sendHederaTransaction = async (testnet: boolean, body: TransferHederaParams) => {
    const { signerPrivateKey, receiverId, amount } = body;
    let { signerId } = body;
    /* 
        can derive public key from privatekey, then generate account id from it.
     */
    let client = await createHederaConnection(testnet)
    const signedTransaction = await new TransferTransaction()
        .addHbarTransfer(signerId, Hbar.fromTinybars(-amount))
        .addHbarTransfer(receiverId, Hbar.fromTinybars(amount))
        .execute(client);
    return signedTransaction;
}

  // SEND SIGNED TRANSACTION
  let recieverAccountId = generateHederaAccountId('302a300506032b6570032100ebcb5483f9f43f99c60d34549b1c374a74f1601b9d729c67703dc21cada5a585')

  let TransferHederaParams = {
    signerId: '0.0.48605126',
    signerPrivateKey: '43045e3124fe3358923defa78241fc30c286e1e30223ef7f3754ebdbccxxxxxxx',
    receiverId: recieverAccountId,
    amount: 4, // 50 tH
  }
  let send = await sendHederaTransaction(true, TransferHederaParams)
  console.log({ send })
```

https://testnet.hederaexplorer.io/search-details/transaction/0.0.48605126-1666132879-360481214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to create a Hedera account using auto-account creation, meaning that the account is created once HBAR is transferred to an alias.

Here's a working code snippet to do just that:

```
const operatorId = AccountId.fromString(process.env.OPERATOR_ID);
const operatorKey = PrivateKey.fromString(process.env.OPERATOR_PVKEY);
const client = Client.forTestnet().setOperator(operatorId, operatorKey);

async function main() {
    //Create the account alias
    // const newAccountKey = PrivateKey.generateED25519();
    const newPrivateKey = PrivateKey.generateECDSA();
    const newPublicKey = newPrivateKey.publicKey;
    const newAliasAccountId = newPublicKey.toAccountId(0, 0);

    //Transfer hbar to the account alias
    const transferToAliasTx = new TransferTransaction()
        .addHbarTransfer(operatorId, new Hbar(-100))
        .addHbarTransfer(newAliasAccountId, new Hbar(100))
        .freezeWith(client);
    const transferToAliasSign = await transferToAliasTx.sign(operatorKey);
    const transferToAliasSubmit = await transferToAliasSign.execute(client);
    const transferToAliasRx = await transferToAliasSubmit.getReceipt(client);

    console.log(`- Transfer status: ${transferToAliasRx.status} \n`);

    // Get a transaction record and query the record
    const transferToAliasRec = await transferToAliasSubmit.getRecord(client);
    const txRec = await new TransactionRecordQuery()
        .setTransactionId(transferToAliasRec.transactionId)
        .setIncludeChildren(true)
        .execute(client);
    console.log(`- New account ID: ${txRec.children[0].receipt.accountId.toString()} \n`);
    console.log(`- Parent transaction ID: ${txRec.transactionId} \n`);
    console.log(`- Child transaction ID: ${txRec.children[0].transactionId.toString()} \n`);
}
```